# Inverting $\frac{\xi}{2}(1+\tanh(\xi))=\lambda$ using the Lagrange-Burmann Theorem

Tags: mathematical-physics, hyperbolic-functions, lagrange-inversion

For my quantum mechanics homework, I developed the transcendental equation $\frac{\xi}{2}(1+\tanh(\xi))$ for the well-posedness of symmetric potential formed from two delta functions. The professor encourages us to use a numerical tool to solve the equation
$$\frac{\xi}{2}(1+\tanh(\xi))=\lambda$$
for $\xi(\lambda)$; however, I was curious if the Lagrange inversion theorem could be employed instead.

Taking $B_n$ to represent a Bernoulli number, we have

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\tanh x &=& x - \frac {x^3} {3} + \frac {2x^5} {15} - \frac {17x^7} {315} + \cdots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2n}(2^{2n}-1)B_{2n} x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}, \left |x \right | < \frac {\pi} {2} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

could I pose the transcendental equation as

$$
\frac{\xi}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2n-1}(2^{2n}-1)B_{2n} \xi^{2n}}{(2n)!} = \lambda
$$

Excerpting from Wikipedia, if $g$ shall be the inverse of $f$, where $f$ is given by a formal power series as
$$f(w) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k\frac{w^k}{k!}$$
$$g(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}g_k\frac{z^k}{k!}$$
then
$$g_1=\frac{1}{f_1}$$
and
$$g_n = \frac{1}{f_1^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^k n^{(k)} \mathcal B_{n-1,k}\left(\frac{f_2}{2f_1},\frac{f_3}{3 f_1},\dots,\frac{f_{n-k+1}}{(n-k+1)f_1}\right)$$
where $n^{(k)}$ is the rising factorial and $\mathcal B$ is a Bell polynomial.

**Question:** Are there any further simplifications that I can use? Currently, the presence of Bell polynomials seems discouraging as the performance of this algorithm. Also, can I work around the stipulation $|\xi|<\frac{\pi}{2}$? There are some solutions that exist outside of that regime for sufficiently high $\lambda$. Could I partition the function $\frac{\xi}{2}(1+\tanh(\xi))$ into intervals of length $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and apply the result to each of them?

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash Good point, that would remove the need for the $2^{n-1}$ factor in the series solution. Do you know of any combinatorial identities for Bell polynomials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Too long for a comment.*

You can write the equation as you did and  use the standard series reversion to have
$$\xi=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {a_n}\,\lambda^n$$ The problem is that the coefficients are almost exploding
$$\left\{2,-4,16,-\frac{224}{3},384,-\frac{10496}{5},\frac{538624}{45
   },-\frac{22171648}{315},\frac{26697728}{63},\cdots\right\}$$

Much better would be to use some $[n+1,n]$ Padé approximant $P_n$. The simplest would be
$$P_2=\frac {\xi  \left(\xi ^2+3 \xi +3\right) } {2 \left(\xi ^2+3\right) }$$ Just to give an idea
$$\Phi_2=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \Big[\frac{1}{2} \xi  (1+\tanh (\xi ))-P_2\Big]^2\, d\xi\sim \pi \times 10^{-4}$$

So, a good *approximation* will be obtained solbing the cubic equation
$$\xi ^3+(3-2 \lambda ) \xi ^2+3 \xi -6 \lambda=0$$
Then, the first estimate
$$\xi_0=\frac{2 \lambda -3}{3}+\frac{4}{3} \sqrt{\lambda(3-\lambda )  } \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{16 \lambda ^3-72
   \lambda ^2+216 \lambda +27}{16 (\lambda(3-\lambda ) 
   )^{3/2}}\right)\right)$$ To polish the root, perform one single iteration of Newton method
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\lambda & \xi_0 & \xi_1 & \text{solution} \\
 0.1 & 0.17103 & 0.17103 &  0.17103 \\
 0.2 & 0.30803 & 0.30802 &  0.30802 \\
 0.3 & 0.42764 & 0.42757 &  0.42757\\
 0.4 & 0.53696 & 0.53673 &  0.53673 \\
 0.5 & 0.63980 & 0.63923 &  0.63923 \\
 0.6 & 0.73851 & 0.73732 &  0.73732 \\
 0.7 & 0.83465 & 0.83245 &  0.83245 \\
 0.8 & 0.92936 & 0.92563 &  0.92563 \\
 0.9 & 1.02353 & 1.01759 &  1.01759 \\
 1.0 & 1.11785 & 1.10886 &  1.10886 \\
 1.1 & 1.21291 & 1.19982 &  1.19982 \\
 1.2 & 1.30920 & 1.29078 &  1.29079 \\
 1.3 & 1.40718 & 1.38194 &  1.38196 \\
 1.4 & 1.50722 & 1.47346 &  1.47350 \\
 1.5 & 1.60970 & 1.56545 &  1.56551 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

*You have made me sixty years younger since this was part of my thesis work*.

**Edit**

I do not know how she did but my wife found a copy of my thesis work. In fact, I also proposed a better approximation, namely
$$\frac{\xi}{2}(1+\tanh(\xi))\sim \xi\,\,\frac{\frac{185}{352}+\frac{124  }{339}\xi+\frac{48 }{89}\xi ^2 } {1+\frac{154 }{247}\xi^2 }$$ which gives a norm equal to $8.68\times 10^{-7}$ ($360$ times smaller than the previous one).

For $\lambda=1.5$, this gives $\xi_0=1.56682$.

Comment: A charming backstory (+1)

Comment: @FShrike. Thanks ! Being blind and messy and so old, I don't know how I could have been able to find it. Moreover, I did not remember my last approximation. Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 4):

We can re-write the equation as
$$
\lambda  = \frac{\xi }{{1 + {\rm e}^{ - 2\xi } }},
$$
i.e.,
$$
- 2\lambda  = \frac{{ - 2\xi }}{{1 + {\rm e}^{ - 2\xi } }}.
$$
Consequently,
$$
2\lambda {\rm e}^{ - 2\lambda }  = \frac{{2\xi }}{{1 + {\rm e}^{ - 2\xi } }}\exp \left( {\frac{{ - 2\xi }}{{1 + {\rm e}^{ - 2\xi } }}} \right)
$$
or
$$
2\lambda {\rm e}^{ - 2\lambda }  = \frac{{2\xi }}{{{\rm e}^{2\xi }  + 1}}\exp \left( {\frac{{2\xi }}{{{\rm e}^{2\xi }  + 1}}} \right).
$$
Hence, in terms of the Lambert $W$-function,
$$
\frac{{2\xi }}{{{\rm e}^{2\xi }  + 1}}=W(2\lambda {\rm e}^{ - 2\lambda } ).
$$
But from the original equation,
$$
\frac{{2\xi }}{{{\rm e}^{2\xi }  + 1}} = 2(\xi  - \lambda ).
$$
Thus,
$$\boxed{
\xi  = \lambda  + \frac{1}{2}W(2\lambda {\rm e}^{ - 2\lambda } ).}
$$
For example, if $|2\lambda {\rm e}^{ - 2\lambda }|<\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}$ (which includes $\lambda \ge 0$), then
$$
\xi  = \lambda  + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - n)^{n - 1} }}{{n!}}(2\lambda {\rm e}^{ - 2\lambda } )^n } .
$$
Indeed, this follows by taking the principal brach of $W$ and using its standard Maclaurin series. Alternatively, by [$\mathrm{A}038049$](https://oeis.org/A038049),
$$
\xi  =  - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\binom{n}{k}k^{n - 1} } } \right)\frac{{( - 2\lambda )^n }}{{n!}}} 
$$
provided $|\lambda|  < \frac{1}{2}W\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\rm e}}} \right) = 0.13923227 \ldots$ ($W$ being the principal branch).

Comment: The first step for the other answers should have been to check if Lambert W solved the equation. You were the first to notice it. Well done (+1)

Comment: This is more than elegant. Why didn't you post it 60 years ago ? Thanks

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks. My father was 1 year old 60 years ago. :D

Comment: I do not see the problem here.  Aren't you able to travel in time ?

Comment: Let's the closed-form functions include Lambert W. Because representations for the closed-form functions are known, we get hints i.a. for its series representations.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a later answer using [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem).You can simplify the equation into:

$$y(\tanh(y)+1)=z\implies y=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}(\tanh(t)+1)^{-n}\right|_{t=0},z=2\lambda$$

The [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y+%28tanh%28y%29%2B1%29%2Cy%3Dsum%5B0.2%5En%2Fn%21+D%5B%281%2F%28tanh%28x%29%2B1%29%29%5En%2C%7Bx%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C10%7D%5D%2Cx%3D0.0) requires finding $n$th derivatives. Rearranging and applying the binomial theorem:

$$\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}(\tanh(t)+1)^{-n}\right|_{t=0}=2^{-n}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}(e^{-2t}+1)^n\right|_{t=0}=2^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}e^{-2kt}\right|_{t=0}$$

After removing the $n=1$ term for no convergence problems. A simplification and radius of convergence is due to @Gary:

$$\boxed{y(\tanh(y)+1)=z\implies y=z-\frac12 \sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k^{n-1}(-z)^n}{k!(n-k)!}}$$

[**Shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x+%28tanh%28x%29%2B1%29%2Cx%3D0.15%2B0.2+i%2Bsum%5B%280.15%2B0.2+i%29%5En%2Fn%21+2%5E%28-1%29+sum%5Bbinom%28n%2Ck%29%28-+k%29%5E%28n-1%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C200%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C2%2C200%7D%5D) without Bell polynomials. Additionally, $k$’s upper bound can go up to $\infty$ with interchangeable sums in that case.. The radius of convergence uses [Lambert W$(z)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lambertw%281%2Fe%29): $|z|<\text W\left(\frac 1e\right),z\in\Bbb C$.

Switching the sums and limiting the index uses the [lower regularized gamma function P$(a,z)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=regularized+gamma+function):

$$y=z-\frac12\lim_{c\to 0}\sum_{n=c,1+c,2+c,\dots}\frac{(-n z)^n\text P(2-n,-nz)}{e^{nz}nn!}$$

[Shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%28tanh%28x%29%2B1%29%2Cx%3D0.2-1%2F2+sum%5B%28e%5E%28-k+0.2%29+%28-k+0.2%29%5Ek+%28%CE%93%282+-+k%29+-+%CE%93%282+-+k%2C+-k+0.2%29%29%29%2F%28k+%CE%93%282+-+k%29+%CE%93%281+%2B+k%29%29%2C%7Bk%2C0.001%2C30.001%7D%5D)

Comment: Note that the final result may be written $$
y =  - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n =1}^\infty  {a_n \frac{{( - z)^n }}{{n!}}} 
$$ with $$
a_n  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n  {\binom{n}{k}k^{n - 1} } .
$$ This is [A038049](https://oeis.org/A038049) in the OEIS.

Comment: From the asymptotics of the $a_n$, the region of convergence is $
\left| z \right| < W(1/{\rm e}) = 0.27846454 \ldots$.

Comment: @Gary Thanks. Your information was added to the post.